# Multiple calls to ServiceObject.Load without reloading data

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm building an object model layer on top of EWS, and am exposing an object that is an EmailMessage, internally, that has several standard properties which I load on startup, and allow the user to have different "views" on that object (ViewAsEntity1, ViewAsEntity2) which loads other custom properties on demand (some are Extended Properties, some Internet Headers).

The problem is that I call Item.Bind() with one PropertySet (the standard properties), but when the user asks to ViewAsEntity1, I call ServiceObject.Load() with the new PropertySet, which either means I lose the original set of properties, or I re-retrieve them.

So my question are:

1) If I call ServiceObject.Load twice, with the same properties in the PropertySet, does Exchange really send the same data over, or does it assume I already have it cached (if it is unchanged), and doesn't send it again? And if so, does EWS know not to clobber the existing data in the PropertyBag?

2) If the answer to #1 is no, what's the best way to avoid expensive EWS calls again and again? I was hoping to keep my Object Model layer thin and simply refer calls to properties into the internal EWS Item object, but if #1 is wrong, I guess I'll have to copy all the data to my objects manually. Is there a better way?

I'm using .NET 4.5, Managed EWS 2.0 and Exchange 2010 SP1

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look at the code for the EWS Managed API.  It seems that every time you call ´ServiceObject.Load()´, the managed EWS API will send an HTTP request to your Exchange server.  There is no caching built into the managed API when using ´ServiceObject.Load()´ which is good in my opinion.  How would the API know when the item on the server has changed and you need a refresh?

There may be some caching on the Exchange server - who knows - but you still have to make the HTTP call.

If you want to spare some HTTP calls you have to build caching into your own client.